# WiFi access point suggestion for SOHO, 3 isolated networks and MAC ACL

Tags: wifi, access-point

I have in all my three locations routers rb2011uias-2hnd-in from Mikrotik. I am satisfied with them, but all they have a weak place: their 2,4GHz WiFi. It is very weak. So weak that there is almost no Wi-Fi on the other end of a 70 square meters apartment, no matter which signal strength is set up.

I know that relocating the routers may help to solve this issue, but they are so well packed or hung in their places, that I wouldn't dare to do this.

So, I am thinking of either buying a simple repeater (this would drop the WiFi speed which is already not good) or buying a separate access point.

Everybody in my environment suggested to buy Ubiquiti, but I found out that they do not have built-in web-interface and are configurable only from a special software, and moreover, the access point gets tied to a device from which it was configured the first time. It is unacceptable.

Actually my router creates three access points: my private, for guests and for work. All they have MAC address access lists. Devices not in these lists are not allowed to connect. Each of these networks is connected to a separate virtual switch inside of the router, with its own DHCP address range and isolation of guest network from host network.

I would like that access point would reproduce these features over single Ethernet cable.

In summary, the desired AP should have the following features:

- Configurable via web interface over Ethernet cable. Not configurable from connected WiFi devices.
- Able to raise 3 WiFi networks, probably with non-overlapping IP address ranges. (I assume that it is not possible to isolate them from each other if they work over the same Ethernet cable, right?)
- MAC address access control white list.
- May be with PoE, but it is not a must.
- And of course it mustn't phone home, like Ubiquiti does.

Are there access points on the market that can meet these requirements?